# postGIS: what is more efficient: single or two-point search

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have seen different approaches to conducting searches.  Which is the best approach in storing the data for database efficiency:
saving both longitude and latitude points

```
longitude
latitude
```

vs saving a generated point from both longitude latitude?

```
POINT(#{longitude} #{latitude})
```

Context: `rails 3.2.18 application`, `postgresql 9.3.4`, `postgis 2.1.3`
Two types of queries are to be conducted for finding objects:

1. Point with radius and
2. Within a polygon

Instinctively, a single point would mean less indexing.
Jason Scheirer's comment below is of the same opinion:

`I would think that having the point geometry pre-generated as a column value would be more efficient than building it for each row on every query.`

However, that does not mean there are underlying mechanics, particularly for the polygon, are more efficient in one mode rather than the other...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "two-point search"?

Comment: longitude + latitude.  As opposed to saving a single data point, as per `POINT(#{longitude} #{latitude})`

Comment: I would think that having the point geometry pre-generated as a column value would be more efficient than building it for each row on every query.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any clarifications to it requested via comments, and it is always easiest to know what is being asked if a question contains a single question mark.

Comment: If I have understand it right the answer is: store the point as a geometry. Because in this case you can use geographic index that are different of normal database indexes (that you can use in the other case). Also, when you make a spatial query you have to generate the geometry for doing it so thats another point in favor.

Answer (score 1):

You mention PostGIS. If you want to use PostGIS, with the spatial functions and spatial index that comes with PostGIS you will have to use the PostGIS geometry or geographic data type.

If you stor latitude and longitude in separate columns you will have to reinvent the wheel to do any spatial calculations.

And a 2d point consists of longitude and latitude or x and y. There is nothing like a longitude point or a latitude point or x-point or y-point.